# insert short date to sql database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

insert parameter mask text box value (shortDate) to sql server 2008 has error 'cannot recognize string as date' my code :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dilivery_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = 
Convert.ToDateTime(recievedDateTxt.Text).ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

don't use `ToShortDateString`, since you going to set `SqlDbType.Date` you can directly set `DateTime` value as below

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dilivery_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = 
Convert.ToDateTime(recievedDateTxt.Text);
```

if you have format for input datetimem, you better use `DateTime.TryParseExact`

```
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
    recievedDateTxt.Text,           // The string you want to parse
    "dd/MM/yyyy",                   // The format of the string you want to parse.
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,   // The culture that was used
                                    // to create the date/time notation
    DateTimeStyles.None,            // Extra flags that control what assumptions
                                    // the parser can make, and where whitespace
                                    // may occur that is ignored.
    out result))                    // Where the parsed result is stored.
{
       // your other codes 
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@dilivery_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = result; 
}
```

Comment: i tried this .. but same error ...the mask text box direction is from right to left

Comment: then, `Convert.ToDateTime(recievedDateTxt.Text)` may fail, what is the value you input?

Comment: i inserted 18 /12 /2013

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TryParseExact()` method

Try This: if your dateformat is : `dd/MM/yyyy`

```
 DateTime result;
 DateTime.TryParseExact(recievedDateTxt.Text,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out result)
 { 
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@dilivery_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value =result;            
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using this method. I am using this method.

```
try
           {
               using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionSetting.SQLDBConnectionString()))
               {
                   con.Open();
                   using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("spName", con))
                   {
                       com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                       com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dilivery_date", Convert.ToDateTime(recievedDateTxt.Text)));
                       using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                       {
                           da.SelectCommand = com;
                           da.Fill(dtResult);
                       }

                   }

               }

               return dtResult;

           }
           catch (Exception)
           {

               throw;
           }
```

Comment: This is just another approach. This is what i am using when passing values to stored procedure.I posted because i thought it might help to someone.